# Variable not incrementing in Windows Batch file recursive loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, command-line

I am an inexperienced working with batch scripts, and was tasked with appending an incrementing number to a log name.  This script uses 7zip's CLI tool to scan zip files, and produce a log.  Here is the relevant bit that I am having trouble with (the "SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion","SET count=1", "_%count%" and "set /a count+=1 bits were added by me):

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET count=1
for /R G: %%g in (*.zip) DO %rundir%\\7za.exe t -r -p"<zip password goes here>" "%%~fg" 1> "%logfolder%\\%%~nxg.log_%count%.txt" set /a count+=1 2>&1
```

The count stays at one, and I am not quite sure how to get it to move.  I primarily write code in Python, and at this point, I am tempted to burn it all down and re-write everything with Python.  I have no idea what the "2>&1" bit of the code even does.  Any help on solving this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `set /a count+=1` in the same line does not make it a new command. Also you are not using the `delayedexpansion` you've set. See how I used `!count!` instead of `%count%`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /R G: %%g in (*.zip) DO (
    set /a count+=1
    %rundir%\7za.exe t -r -p"<zip password goes here>" "%%~fg" >>"%logfolder%\%%~nxg.log_!count!.txt" 2>&1
 )
```

As for `2>&1` it simply redirects `stderr` to `stdout` I am however not sure why you would require that for `set /a count+=1` So do not add it, we can add it though for the `7za` command in order to log `stdout` and `stderr` to the log files(which I already did)

Comment: Thank you much, it works!  I appreciate the help with the code itself, as well as the explanation for the "2>&1" bits.